# How to display a.txt file from a URL and make each item clickable?

Tags: android

I am having a little trouble in making fully functional App where Displaying .txt file from url in android app , making each displayed item clickable with  message or link or anything .

If someone  already know any examples anywhere where i can look up please give links.

Please kindly help .

Comment: This site does not work this way. Show us the code that you wrote, explain where is the problem and we will help you. If you're looking for code examples - use google.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack overflow.

Generally questions like this are not allowed as the site doesn't work like that. Before asking a question do some research, make a few attempts, then show us what you have done then we can assist you.

Just a tip, break down what you are trying to do into bites.
First look at reading your file, [here's an example](http://www.java67.com/2016/07/how-to-read-text-file-into-arraylist-in-java.html) to get you started by reading the file into an array list.

Next work on displaying the list by displaying it in an recyclerview, [here's a nice example](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/) to get you started. The recyclerview will allow the items to be clickable and you can customize the click event to show messages like you require.

Good luck.